# Repeat mode для фигуры для фона

Tags: android, xml

Делаю разделитель `divider`, фоном которого должны быть простые кружочки. Если этот фон делаю через `Bitmap`, то в нем выставляю `tileMode=Repeat` и работает как надо, но т.к это кружочек из картинки файла, то выглядит он нечетко.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввиду этого решил сделать кружок векторным:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#b5aba2"/>

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Но `Bitmap` не принимает в качестве источника такую фигуру, а кроме как у `Bitmap` я больше нигде не нашел `tileMode=Repeat`, а без этого режима один такой кружок-фигуру растягивает на всю длину разделителя. Подскажите, как это осуществить с фигурой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kotlin:**

```
class DotsDivider : View {

private val numberOfCircles = 20f
private val paint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

init {
    paint.color = Color.LTGRAY
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
}

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    val width = canvas.width
    paint.strokeWidth = canvas.height/2f
    paint.pathEffect = getDashPathEffect(width)
    canvas.drawLine(width/numberOfCircles/2f, canvas.height/2f, canvas.width.toFloat(), canvas.height/2f, paint)
}

private fun getDashPathEffect(width: Int): DashPathEffect{
    return DashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(0f, width/numberOfCircles), width/numberOfCircles*2)
  }
}
```

**Java:**

```
public class DotsDivider extends View {

    private final float numberOfCircles = 20f;
    private final Paint paint;

    {
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    public DotsDividerJava(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DotsDividerJava(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DotsDividerJava(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(canvas.getHeight() / 2);
        paint.setPathEffect(getDashPathEffect(width));
        canvas.drawLine(
                width/numberOfCircles / 2f,
                canvas.getHeight() / 2f,
                canvas.getWidth(),
                canvas.getHeight() / 2f,
                paint);
    }
private DashPathEffect getDashPathEffect(int width){
    return new DashPathEffect(new float[]{0f, width/numberOfCircles}, width/numberOfCircles*2);
    }
}
```

в **xml**:

```
<DotsDivider
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"/>
```

В итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ps: этот пример можно улучшить, можно создать свои reference для новых атрибутов, цвета, кол-ва или изменить логику.

Comment: А во что обернуть в `xml` `DotsDivider`? В голом виде, как выше, ругается.

Comment: так что получилось? я так старался кружочки рисовал, никто плюсики не ставит вам в Java класс этот написать?

Comment: Я, если честно, так и не допер как сделать, чтобы данное решение заработало и в итоге сделал по-другому. Если Вас не затруднит, пожалуйста, распишите как это сделать, на будущее буду знать, если встретятся похожие задачи =)

Comment: ну на самом деле всё так просто как в ответе, вы просто создаете свой класс, как выше (Kotlin). А потом в XML где хотите в проекте используете его и будет такой результат. Я сейчас этот класс для джавы сковертирую скину. мб получится. ПРосто я даже себе сохранил это решение, ибо в инете ничего нет, вопрос то хороший.

Comment: да, соглашусь. в инете информации толковой на эту тему нет. много перелопатил, прежде чем сюда написать

Comment: попробуйте Java кусок, должно работать